# How can I remove a corrupted multiindex table from RAM

Tags: multi-index

Ok, so I made a beginner coding error in a token contract, mis-typing the return value from `get` without `&` (yes, I *now* see the Warning in the docs at https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.cdt/latest/classeosio_1_1multi__index/#function-get) and wound up with a corrupted stat table. I can't erase it because it no longer matches the abi table definitions and accessing it throws an error.

The only thing I have thought of is to reverse-engineer a table declaration under which the corrupted table is readable, then upload code which does an `erase` loop using that.

Using the chain API `get_table_rows` I get the following response from the corrupted table:

```
"rows":["0100000000000000000000000000000004534545445300000070520a83a920cdc0e94558d1339db9"]
```

Any suggestions for a suitable table declaration? Or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: I've not tried it but something like this may help https://github.com/liquidapps-io/eos-contracts-best-practices#deleting-table-rows-without-declaring-tables

Comment: @Nat that worked great! Although it feels odd using a function declared `internal_use_do_not_use::db_lowerbound_i64` ;)

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then : )

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following from here: https://github.com/liquidapps-io/eos-contracts-best-practices#deleting-table-rows-without-declaring-tables

**Deleting table rows without declaring tables**

```
  void clear_secondary_idx256(name TableName, uint8_t index_num, uint64_t scope){
    uint64_t primary = 0;

    auto key = eosio::key256();
    auto it2 = eosio::_multi_index_detail::secondary_index_db_functions<key256>::db_idx_lowerbound(
      _self.value, 
      scope, 
      (static_cast<uint64_t>(TableName.value) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0ULL)
                                    | (index_num & 0x000000000000000FULL), 
      key, 
      primary);
    while (it2 >= 0) {
        auto del = it2;
        uint64_t dummy;
        it2 = db_idx256_next(it2, &dummy);
        db_idx256_remove(del);
    }
  }
  void clear_primary(name TableName, uint64_t scope){
    auto it = db_lowerbound_i64(_self.value, scope, TableName.value, 0);
    while (it >= 0) {
        auto del = it;
        uint64_t dummy;
        it = db_next_i64(it, &dummy);
        db_remove_i64(del);
    }
  }

  ACTION clearpkgs(){
    require_auth(_self);
    clear_primary("package"_n, _self.value);
    clear_secondary_idx256("package"_n, 0, _self.value);
    clear_secondary_idx256("package"_n, 1, _self.value);
  }
```